# React UseSelector with render upon variable change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm attempting to retrieve a filtered array from state with Redux based on a selected value (*selectedNum*) in the component. However, the re-render doesn't seem to fire to call the useSelector after the selectNumberHandler has fired.

I've attempted to filter the numbers array in the handler itself but that didn't seem to filter the rendered numbers in the global scope either.

I've also tried adding the following to no avail (doesn't hit the debugger point after setting the var in the onChange):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
  }, [selectedNum]);
```

Could you please assist me in finding a solution and best practices for this sort of thing?

```
const MyFunction = () => {
  let selectedNum: number;
  let numbers = useSelector(filterNumbers(selectedNum));

  const selectNumberHandler (selectedValue) => {
      selectedNum = selectedValue;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={e => selectNumberHandler(e)}>
        <option value='1' >1</option>
        <option value='2' >2</option>
      </select>
      <div className={'numbers-list'}>
        {numbers.map(num => {
          <p>{num}</p>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where is the `filterNumbers` method and what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useSelector` takes a function of state as the argument.  State being the state of the redux store.  Like this:

```js
const numbers = useSelector(state => somewhereinstate.number);
```

In this way, we can select variables out of the redux store.  What you seem to be trying to do is update the `selectedNum` variable.  But I don't see where you're dispatching that update to the store.  Your `useEffect` doesn't fire because it depends on `selectedNum`.  Your `selectNumberHandler` might alter `selectedNum`, but your component doesn't know that, because `selectedNum` is not a state variable in the component.

So you kind of need to decide: are you keeping the state local to the component, or are you communicating through the store?

#### Local to the component - no `useSelector`

```js
const MyFunction = () => {

  const [selectedNumber, setSelectedNumber] = useState(1)
  const [filteredNumbers, setFilteredNumbers] = useState([])

  useEfect( () => {
    setFilteredNumbers(selectedNumber)
  }, [selectedNumber])

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={e => setSelectedNumber(e.value)}>
        <option value='1' >1</option>
        <option value='2' >2</option>
      </select>
      <div className={'numbers-list'}>
        {filteredNumbers.map(num => {
          <p>{num}</p>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Through redux store, with `useDispatch` and `useSelector`

```js
const MyFunction = () => {

  const numbers = useSelector(state => state.yourValues);
  const dispatch = useDispatch()


  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={e => dispatch( setYourValues(e.value) )}>
        <option value='1' >1</option>
        <option value='2' >2</option>
      </select>
      <div className={'numbers-list'}>
        {numbers.map(num => {
          <p>{num}</p>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

where `setYourValue` is a function that creates an action to update the `yourValue` in the redux store.

Hopefully that gives you some direction.

Comment: There is still one issue that remains. Initially populating the state filteredNumbers variable with the UseSelector from Redux ie pulling the dat in initially from Redux to local state. When/how should this be done in the local approach?

Comment: as the argument of `useState()`.  You'll see that I wrote `const [filteredNumbers, setFilteredNumbers] = useState([])`, which initializes `filteredNumbers` as an empty array.  whatever you put inside `useState` is the value of that variable when the component loads.  if you leave it empty, the variable will be considered undefined.

Comment: I tried to place the following in the useState as useState(useSelector(filterNumbers(selectedNum))), however this doesn't seem to initialize the array with the values sourced from the selector. Is there an order of operations going into effect here that would prevent the initialization of the useSelector?

Comment: `useSelector(filterNumbers(selectedNum))` is very messy. Again, `useSelector` is designed to select part of state from the redux store.  What is `filterNumbers()`?  It should be a function in the form of `state => state.some.piece.of.state`.  So let's say you do that, and write `const initialState = useSelector(state => state.thing)`.  Then you'd be writing `useState(initialState)`.  Maybe that would work.  But why?  Where do you want your state to live?  I would choose one.  Either select an initial value from the store, or initialize a local state variable with `useState(someInitialValue)`